# Importance of Nginx Server without static content

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

As per my knowledge, Nginx Server is best known for

1. Serving Static Contents
2. Proxy and load balancing

I am using Auto Scaling ELB of Amazon and my server is a complete REST server without any static file.

Please let me know if there are any other reason for using Nginx which might be beneficial for my server.